# Using preventDefault for a View

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex-spark, flash-builder4.5

I've created a simple TabbedViewNavigatorApplication. Two of the tabs are going to send text and email, respectively, rather than load a new View.  So I need to prevent the default behavior of pushing the new View.

Documentation says [a view can cancel a navigation operation by canceling its FlexEvent.REMOVING](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/View+and+ViewNavigator). However, there apparently is no such Constant for [FlexEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/FlexEvent.html). There is, however, for ViewNavigatorEvent, as described farther down on that first link.

So here's what I've got, but I neither see the trace statements nor am able to stop the navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160" creationComplete="completeHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

        private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            vwText.addEventListener(ViewNavigatorEvent.REMOVING, removingHandler);
        }

        private function removingHandler(e:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {
            trace("removingHandler::");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        private function doSomething(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("Do Something");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:ViewNavigator  id="vwText" label="Text" width="100%" height="100%" click="doSomething(event)" firstView="views.SendasTextView"/>
<s:ViewNavigator  label="Email" width="100%" height="100%"  firstView="views.SendasEmailView"/>
<s:ViewNavigator label="History" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.HistoryView"/>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take

```
vwText.addEventListener(ViewNavigatorEvent.REMOVING, doSomething);
```

out of your script block.

It needs to be inside of a function. You can use the creationComplete event to create an init function that will add that listener.

Comment: Doh! Yes did that and edited the above code to reflect it. Still not working. Neither of the traces are running either.